# Is there a function in AHK(autohotkey) to move only the Y axis of your mouse?

Tags: autohotkey

So I'm new to AHK and I googled a lot before landing here, but I can't find anything that answers my question. I want to make a script that only moves the Y axis from the mouse but relative to the position of the mouse. For example if the center of my screen is 683,384 and my mouse is at 630, and 389, and I want that the X axis stays but the Y axis goes back where the middle should be

Here's what I mean drawn in paint.. Red is the center black are the X and Y axis yellow is the mouse and blue the desired movement
[image: img]

and if it's always the same spot it would be easy, but I want it to be able to go to the center(relative to the mouse) no matter if its more up or more down that shown in the picture if you know any solutions please help me. Thank you for taking your time reading this

Comment: What's the problem with MouseGetPos followed with MouseMove?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Super easy to do with `MouseGetPos`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MouseGetPos.htm)</sup> and `MouseMove`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MouseMove.htm)</sup>.
First get the current X coordinate, and then move the cursor to that X coordinate along with an Y coordinate that's half of the screen height.<sup>(`A_ScreenHeight`<sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm#Screen)</sup> can be used)</sup>

Also remember to specify the desired [CoordMode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/CoordMode.htm), which is this case is going to be `Screen`, as opposed to the default which would be the active window.

---

Example for F1 as the hotkey.

```
CoordMode, Mouse, Screen

F1::
    MouseGetPos, X
    MouseMove, % X, % A_ScreenHeight / 2, 0
return
```

Comment: Credit Martheen if applicable? Nice well-cited answer in any case.

Comment: Not applicable. Was writing the answer already before the comment arrived, and don't think a common sense solution has anyone to credit.